# MySQL searching text and linking tables

Tags: mysql, string, select, join, sql-like

I have 3 tables in my DB, tbl_user, tbl_games and tbl_usergames.

tbl_user has id and name.

tbl_games has id and name.

tbl_usergames has id_user and id_game and link tbl_user to tbl_games

I want to make a search that return users who has any game that the name match with the search string.

```
SELECT tbl_user.*
FROM tbl_user, tbl_usergames 
WHERE tbl_user.id IN (
 **SELECT id
 FROM tbl_games
 WHERE name LIKE '%Mario%'**
)
```

I tryed this but it return 0 results.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Comment: yes, maybe. I think you're exagerating a bit. My objective by this comment was to point out the necessity for the OP to learn SQL properly, mentionning an example of friendly tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.*
FROM tbl_user u
JOIN tbl_usergames ug ON (u.id = ug.id_user)
JOIN tbl_games g ON (ug.id_game = g.id)
WHERE
    g.name LIKE '%Mario%'
```

You need to join on *both* tables.